# How to loop my key in Vigenere Cipher

Tags: c, vigenere

I'm writing a program for Vigenere Cipher. But I don't know how to make my key repeat til the end of my plain text. Right now what my code does is encrypt only the letters which are equivalent to the number of letter my key has. For example I enter a key of "dog" and my plain text is "catdog", it gives me an encrypted text of "fozdyw". Which means it is only encrypting the first 3 letters.

This is a bit of my code that does the encrypting:

```
for (int j=0, k=0; j < strlen(text); j++, k++)
      {         
        if((text[j] >= 'A') && (text[j] <= 'Z'))
            text[j] = ((text[j] -'A') + key[k]) % 26 +'A';

        if((text[j] >= 'a') && (text[j] <= 'z'))
            text[j] = ((text[j] -'a') + key[k]) % 26 +'a';

        printf("%c", text[j]); 
      }
```

What am I doing wrong? And what should be the right thing to do?

Comment: Well...you appear to know about the modulus operator. Consider using it for this too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to the end of the key, go back to index 0, this is done by using the remainder of the division by the size of the key (AKA modulus):

```
  for (int j=0, k=0; j < strlen(text); j++, k++)
  {         
    if((text[j] >= 'A') && (text[j] <= 'Z'))
        text[j] = ((text[j] -'A') + key[k % size_of_the_key]) % 26 +'A';

    if((text[j] >= 'a') && (text[j] <= 'z'))
        text[j] = ((text[j] -'a') + key[k % size_of_the_key]) % 26 +'a';

    printf("%c", text[j]); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Binyamin Sharet. It did work. Just one more question if you dont mind. I want my code to ignore the spaces and symbols. Any suggestion how would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with them. if you want to remove them from the encrypted payload you can add an index to where do you assign in "text" and don't increment it when reaching such character. But you will need to handle the index of the key anyway, and not increment it when you reach such letter.

Answer (score 0):

the ascii table is a good reference for that. that is, preventing symbols from being encrypted. to be precise, endavour to work with a speific range of letters. for instance between 65 and 90 for uppercase else terminate that program.